# ng-options (array in object.property)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I'm stuck on one problem, I have a structure like this

```
let test = {
            general:[
                'call_id',
                'name',
                'value'
            ],
            agents: [
                'agent_id',
                'agent_name'
        ],
           grp_stats:[
               'group_name',
               'group_id'
        ] 
        }
```

Is it possible to make ng-options so I can group elements in one select by keys (grp_stats,agents,general) and use array values as options? So kind of combine object properties selection and getting array values from object properties.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume this is AngularJS (version 1.x) and not Angular (version 2+)? I've edited the tag appropriately.

Comment: You mean like a nested dropdown? Click the select, the keys dropdown, click one of them, another dropdown displays from it with the array options?

Comment: Devin, yes, something like that

Comment: DeborahK, thank you, its AngularJS (version 1.x).